# Android store test subscription cancellation

Tags: android, google-play, android-billing

I am trying to teat a yearly subscription, I added my email to tester, I subscribed with "test card, always approved" and I received emails saying renewal happened, like it is here:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test#renewals

But if I fetch using the billing api, it says my subscription will expire in a year. If I go to
'manage subscriptions", I only see my real subscriptions.

So how can I cancel a subscription, and actually remove the subscription to be able to retest subscribing?

Answer (score -1):

If you retrieve details using the billing API, it will consistently indicate an actual period. However, it is important to note that, in reality, the subscription is renewed every 30 minutes due to its nature as a test subscription.

If you cannot locate the test subscription on the Play Store, consider verifying it with a different email address. Try switching to an alternate profile within the Play Store app.